# Rename field name in geokettle

Tags: javascript, pentaho, geokettle

Greeting,
I want to rename a field using "Modified Java Script Value" script.

For example I have Input field "field1" and I want to rename it using JavaScript to "NewField".

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

The Rename-To option for output fields is not working as expected.  Existing fields can not be renamed as of Kettle version 6.1.  Renaming works for new fields, but that's hardly a feature we need. Use the Rename-To field option provided by Select-Values, which is the preferred and documented way to do this.